# React component testing with Jest

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I want to test my components using jest, but when I run it i am getting 
`Cannot find module 'react-router/Router' from 'Router.js'

```
  at Resolver.resolveModule (node_modules/jest-resolve/build/index.js:191:17)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/react-router-dom/Router.js:5:15)`
```

if I start development server my application is working corectly.

My jest config in package.json looks like:

```
 "jest": {
    "testPathIgnorePatterns": [
      "/node_modules/"
    ],
    "moduleDirectories": [
      "<rootDir>/node_modules",
      "<rootDir>/src"
    ]
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are overwriting [`moduleDirectories`](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/configuration.html#moduledirectories-array-string) and you don't include the default, which is `["node_modules"]`. You are including `<rootDir>/node_modules` instead, which is not the same, because that will only look into the `node_modules` in the root of your project, whereas `"node_modules"` follows the module resolution of Node.js. The behaviour of Node.js is to look for `node_modules` in the current directory, if the module is not found it looks in its parent directory (`../node_modules`) and so on until the module was found or the root of your file system is reached. For more details see [Loading from `node_modules` Folders](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_loading_from_node_modules_folders).

The important difference is that nested modules break if you change the default behaviour. In your case `react-router-dom` uses [`react-router` as a dependency](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router-dom/package.json#L47), and the `node_modules` might look like this:

```
node_modules
├─ jest
└─ react-router-dom
    └─ node_modules
        └─ react-router
```

In this example, `node_modules` in the root directory only contains `jest` and `react-router-dom`, so it wouldn't find `react-router`.

*Note: npm started hoisting dependencies with version 3 and the result would look like this:*

```
node_modules
├─ jest
├─ react-router-dom
└─ react-router
```

See also [npm v3 Dependency Resolution](https://docs.npmjs.com/how-npm-works/npm3).

If you are indeed using a severely outdated npm version, you should upgrade immediately. But you should never rely on that behaviour, and always include the default module resolution.

```
"jest": {
  "testPathIgnorePatterns": [
    "/node_modules/"
  ],
  "moduleDirectories": [
    "node_modules",
    "<rootDir>/src"
  ]
}
```